# Crypto Currency gives an error when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, compiler-errors

I have a crypto currency I've been working on. Its based off of the cryptonote deference code. When I run a build in Travis Ci it fails. I can't figure out what the error is referencing.

edit:removed personal detail................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your version of G++ does not recognize the options `-std=c11` and `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`- in other words, your compiler is too old. It must be quite ancient to not recognize `-std=c11`.

Comment: I'm compiling it with gcc not G++ I tried updating gcc to 4.8 from 4.6 and I still get the error.